# Automatic Jacobian matrix in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ode, hmatrix

I'm trying to solve an ODE set, but I've run into some problems, as the set I'm looking into is very stiff. My related experience is low, but I've understood that my next step should be to include a jacobian matrix in the solver I'm using.

My current setup uses [OdeSolveV](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-gsl-0.19.0.1/docs/Numeric-GSL-ODE.html) from [Numeric.GSL.Ode](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-gsl-0.19.0.1) with `ODEMethod RKf45`. My goal is to upgrade `ODEMethod` to `BSimp`. An example with an included jacobian is given in the [ODE examples](https://github.com/haskell-numerics/hmatrix/blob/master/examples/ode.hs) for `hmatrix`:

```
vanderpol' mu = do
    let xdot mu t (toList->[x,v]) = fromList [v, -x + mu * v * (1-x^2)]
        jac t (toList->[x,v]) = (2><2) [ 0          ,          1
                                       , -1-2*x*v*mu, mu*(1-x**2) ]
        ts = linspace 1000 (0,50)
        hi = (ts!1 - ts!0)/100
        sol = toColumns $ odeSolveV (MSBDF jac) hi 1E-8 1E-8 (xdot mu) (fromList [1,0]) ts
    mplot sol
```

To my understanding this function `jac` returns the jacobian matrix with the current values of `x` and `v`. This is quite straightforward thus far, unless I've missed something. However, the system I'm working with has not 2, but 35 parameters, and I would like to not do this matrix by hand, so I'm trying to figure out a way to do this automatically.

[Numeric.AD.Jacobian](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad-4.5.5/docs/Numeric-AD-Jacobian.html) seems to have a way of giving me exactly this, but I do not understand how to implement it. What I think I want in this scenario is a function `jac` that returns the jacobian matrix based on `xdot` and the passed in parameters. Is this viable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (albeit not necessarily most elegant) solution is to define `xdot` as a list function over polymorphic numerical arguments, as those can be instantiated to either directly the number type used for the ODE solver, or the automatic-differentiation value-infinitesimal pairs. Then you just wrap each version in vectors/matrices as required for the solver:

```
import Numeric.GSL.ODE
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra
import Numeric.AD

vanderpol :: Vector Double  -- ^ Time points
         -> [Vector Double]
vanderpol ts = toColumns $
         odeSolveV (BSimp $ \t -> fromLists . jac t . toList)
                   0.1 1e-8 1e-8
                   (\t -> fromList . xdot t . toList)
                   (fromList [0.5,0]) ts
 where xdot :: Num a => a -> [a] -> [a]
       xdot t [x,v] = [v, -x*(1-x^2)]
       jac :: Double -> [Double] -> [[Double]]
       jac t = jacobian (xdot $ realToFrac t)
```

The `realToFrac` is required because from the perspective of `jac`, `xdot` does not accept a `Double` argument but rather a `Reverse s Double` argument.

Comment: I have some follow up questions (feels like a lot went over my head): Does the ^ in your comment on the first line symbolise anything? Is it true that your solution doesn't rely on other imports other than the ones used in the example code? It seems like you're assigning the result of `toColumns $ odeSolveV` to `ts` - is this correct? Shouldn't it go to something else, like `solution`?

Comment: https://haskell-haddock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#function-arguments ⫽ Imports [`Numeric.AD`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad-4.5.5/docs/Numeric-AD.html) ⫽ No, `ts` is just the argument of the `vanderpol` function. The result isn't assigned to anything here.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see now - I simply mixed things up here. Thank you.
It took some time to realise that you changed the example a bit - but I prefer your version for `ts`.